# if a series is convergent, prove the subsequence of its sequence is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is a convergent series of positive numbers, 

and if $\{ a_{n_i} \}$ is a subsequence of $\{ a_n \}$ , ( n , i are Natural numbers ), 
prove $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{n_i}$ converges.

My idea is: since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges , then $\{ a_n \}$ converges ( to zero ), hence its subsequence $\{ a_{n_i} \}$ converges ( to zero ). 
Now I want to show the sequence of partial sums of $\{ a_{n_i} \}$ is bounded, to prove the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{n_i}$ is convergent. 
I do not know how to show this. or is my idea correct in the first place.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to note that 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{n_{i}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{n_{N}}a_{n}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n},
\end{align*}
and hence the partial sums $\left\{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_{n_{i}}\right\}_{N=1}^{\infty}$ are bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A:=\{n(i):i \in \Bbb{N}\} \subseteq \Bbb{N}$

Then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{n(i)}=\sum_{n \in A}a_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<+\infty$